# ¿Como obtener los resultados de una lista ordenada indiferentemente de mayúsculas y minúsculas?

Tags: python-3.7

Hola me gustaría saber como hacer una búsqueda en una lista ordenada. Bien necesito extraer todos los resultados que coincidan con la búsqueda indiferentemente de las mayúsculas y minúsculas.

Tengo un requisito, el resultado tiene que estar escrito igualmente que la lista original. Por lo tanto no puedo modificar a minúsculas ni mayúsculas la lista original.

E conseguido montar este ejemplo pero estoy atrancado en el:

```
a = ["Caracol", "Caramelo", "Arco", "Aranjuez ", "amarillo", "Tengo una camioneta"]
a.sort(key = str.lower)

for item in a:
    if "c" in item:
         print(item)
```

Bien el resultado

Arco
Caracol
Tengo una camioneta

En ese resultado me falta Caramelo.
Agradecido a quien pueda echarme un poco de luz.

Comment: Te falta _Caramelo_ porque "C" y "c" son distintas, sin embargo las otras cadenas si que tienen una "c" en alguna posición

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solo tienes que asegurarte que buscas el carácter o bien todo mayusculas o todo minusculas. Añadiendo `item.lower()` te da el resultado que buscas.

```
a = ["Caracol", "Caramelo", "Arco", "Aranjuez ", "amarillo", "Tengo una camioneta"]
a.sort(key = str.lower)

for item in a:
    if "c" in item.lower():
         print(item)
```

Añade un `input().lower()` antes del for para que el usuario busque la cadena que quiera sin importar si está en mayusculas o minusculas.

```
b = input("Buscar: ").lower()

for item in a:
    if b in item.lower():
        print(item)
```

Comment: Te entiendo, pero habia dejado eso como ejercicio para tí. En ese caso lo que tendrías que hacer es intercalar un `busco = input("Buscar: ").lower()` antes del for y cambiar tu "c" por la variable `busco` (o el nombre que quieras darle)